# How to "Chamfer" or Bevel Outer Edges of a Plane like in 3DS Max?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edges, bevel

I've been following Grant Warwick's hardsurface modeling essentials video on Vimeo, using Blender 2.80. Following the tutorial, I've made a basic hill-type shape by extruding a plane multiple times in edit mode.

[image]

Warwick, using 3ds max, was able to select the outer edges of the mesh and "chamfer"/bevel it. I used the knife tool to show what he did:

[image: Ideal Bevel of Outer Edge]

When I try doing the same in Blender 2.8, however, I can't seem to bevel the outer edge of a plane/mesh. So, I try adding a loop cut instead. But the edge flow doesn't go all the way around the mesh; I can only add one loop cut vertically, or one cut horizontally:

[image]

Is there a way to bevel an outer edge of a plane/mesh in Blender? How can I do what I did with the knife tool, to get an even edge without too many manual steps? Is that possible in Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an edge selection,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, Offset Edge Slide, will get you most of the way there. It will slide a copy of selected edges along existing ones, and can be set to give an even offset. However, it doesn't *create* rail edges (in your case, at the corners) where they did not previously exist .. you would have to go round and <kbd>J</kbd> connect the vertices at the corners.

If you had to do so many of those it would be tedious, you could:

- Extrude your selected edges any old where, so they are no longer on a boundary
- Select the top faces <kbd>I</kbd> and inset the whole region with 'Boundary' unchecked
- Alt-select the extruded face ring, and delete it.

Or, you could go round with <kbd>K</kbd> cutting across existing edges, making a  rough inset, and create the corner-rails, with no concern for accuracy, and then use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide it, hitting <kbd>E</kbd> to make the edges parallel to the boundary. (<kbd>F</kbd> flips which side of the slide to be parallel to.)

Comment: Thank you, this I think is as close to what I wanted as possible.

Comment: @CPLTarun    It's been a while since I used 3DS in anger.. but I think I prefer a set of tools that is as near as possible complete and minimal.. rather than rifling the drawers for a gadget that does _exactly_  x or y, if only I could remember where to find it. What I miss, though, are soft selections, and being able to edit in the modifier stack.